# projecting a document from an array based a filter cond

Tags: mongodb

I have a rather a bit complex document, but here is the sample I can put it here.

I have 'addresses' array that has multiple addresses documents something like

```
addresses : [
           {'code': '1', line:'abc town'}, {'code':'2', line:'bcd town'},{'code':'3', line: 'another town'}
```

]

and I want to pull the document based on the code. for example code:1 then just pull this one document if not look if there is code:2, yes then pull this document, else pull anything else is available

my document structure looks like this

```
[
 _id:123
  fn: 'name',
  addresses : [
               {'code': '1', line:'abc town'}, {'code':'2', line:'bcd town'},{'code':'3', line: 'another town'}
 ]
```

]

and the query I wrote is

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {'_id':123}},
{$project: {
"fn" :1,
    "addresses": {$filter: {
        input: '$addresses',
        as: 'address',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$address.code', '1']}
    }},
    _id: 0
}}
```

it works when the code is equal to 1 (obviously) but I am not sure how to do "if else" condition I need the way I explained above that is if code ==1 then pull only that document if not look if code ==2 then pull that document if not all else pull whatever is available.

I know this is complex to explain but I think I need some fix in my $filter cond.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This should get you on the right track:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: hey thanks for the link. I do think I am on the right track it is just that I am not able to do the if else in $filter condition. if you can please correct the mistake I am making.

Comment: JohnnyHK .. by any chance, have you looked at this one?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will work, I also do not know what comparison you are trying to perform. If you give me that information, I will recreate the dataset and try it at my end.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {'_id':123}},
{$project: {
"fn" :1,
    "addresses": {$cond: {
        if: {$eq: ["YOUR_EXPRESSION": 1]},
        then: "addresses.0.line",
        else: "addresses.1.line"
    }},
    _id: 0
}}
```